# Java. Некоректная работа indexOf

Tags: java, сортировка, list, arraylist

Здравствуйте, пишу базу данных на Java и пытаюсь сделать сортировку по месту.

```
    private void sortByPlace() {
    ArrayList<String> tmpplace = place; 
    Collections.sort(place);
    for (int i = 0; i < place.size(); i++) {
        name.set(i, name.get(tmpplace.indexOf(place.get(i))));
        surname.set(i, surname.get(tmpplace.indexOf(place.get(i))));
    }
    printDB();
    menu();
}
```

Алгоритм такой:

1)Создаю временный list tmpplace и записываю в него place.

2)Сортирую place.

3)Изменяю name и surname так, чтобы они соответствовали изменившемуся place.

Почему tmpplace.indexOf(place.get(i)) = i? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Вы не создаете временный список, вы просто копируете ссылку на него. У вас не дав списка, он все равно один. Вы можете создать новый, вызвав `new ArrayList<>(place);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Написав ArrayList tmpplace  = place, вы тем самым не записали объект в новый объект, а поместили ссылку на объект. Обе ваши переменные ссылаются на один объект в памяти, грубо говоря отсортировали один - отсортировался другой.Поэтому не удивительно, что когда вы ищете первое вхождение i-того элемента массива у этого же массива он вам возвращает i.